# JPG segment length encoding

Tags: jpeg, exif

I'm trying to write some code to extract Exif information from a JPG.

Exif is stored in the APP1 segment of a JPG file. According to [the Exif spec](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF), the format of the APP1 segment is supposed to start like this:

```
FF E1        // APP1 segment marker
nn nn        // Length of segment
45           // 'E'
78           // 'x'
69           // 'i'
66           // 'f'
```

And it goes until there is an `FF` followed by something other than `FF` or `00`.

Looking at a JPG in a hex editor, I can see `FF E1` and the `Exif` string, but I'm having trouble decoding the length bytes. An example: In one jpg, my hex editor tells me the APP1 segment is 686 bytes long, but the length bytes are `F7 C8`.

How should I use those bytes to come up with 686 decimal?

**Edit:** Here is the first part of the example file:

```
FF D8 FF E1 F7 C8 45 78 69 66 00 00 4D 4D 00 2A 00 00 00 08
```

**Edit:** Actually, I think I might know what's going on here. Does the APP1 segment actually "contain" other segments? For example, if the thumbnail data were considered to be inside APP1, then that length seems more reasonable. Can anyone confirm/deny this?

Comment: Are you sure the APP1 segment isn't 63432 bytes? How do you know it's 686? It's probably 686 plus the size of the thumbnail.

Comment: @gabe I looked for the next `FF xx` marker bytes of a new segment. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I would expect an FFDB to be the next marker (DQT).

Comment: (I'm confused where 686 comes from)

Comment: @pst 686 is the number of bytes until the next marker, which is `FF D8` (SOI) immediately followed by `FF DB` (DQT).

Comment: @gabe looks like you are absolutely correct. Counting 63432 bytes down the last thing inside it is an `FF D9` (to mark the end of the thumbnail I guess) and then there's an `FF DB` (DQT for the actual image). If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the APP1 segment includes the thumbnail (see the linked EXIF document and scroll down to logical page 12), so the 686 is a red herring (probably the number of bytes until the thumbnail). F7C8 is the actual number of bytes until the DQT segment, and it's so big because it includes a thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Those bytes don't represent 686, but the length bytes do preceed the "Exif" string.

Without seeing the file, it's impossible to diagnose.  It might be good to post the first 20 hex bytes of your file.